# Transaction in AD modification

Tags: active-directory

Is there any tool that bring in "transaction" in AD object modification that you can roll back?

While it shall be also useful in production environment , I'm asking this because I'm studying AD and will usually practice some experiment on the VM -- and afterward I do want to revert back to the original status before experiment.

Certainly I can log every step I did and do reversely but it's just kind of wasting time, if there's a 'roll back' there.

Comment: No, unfortunately, Active Directory is **not** a transactional store, you don't get any of those benefits, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Transactions are not implemented in Active-Directory. Even if most of the time Directories are built on the top of databases you must know that transactions are not discribed in LDAP standard and can only be implemented in an editor way. It exists some experimental RFC for  [Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) Transactions (5805)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5805) but it's a kind of "graal".

For your problem, if you are running a single DC inside a VM, just take a "snapshot" if your VM tool allow it (like VMWare does), or just backup your VM files before your modifications.

With Active-Directory you don't *PLAY* in production. The only way to go back is an **authoritative Restore**.

JP

Comment: Thanks JP -- yes I also considered restore VM snapshot but it's too heavyweight and I might just undo the changes as it takes to restore a snapshot.